# Define equations and binary variables

Tags: glpk, mathprog

```
var x11>=0; var x21>=0;
var x11b binary; var x12b binary;
s.t. eq1: (50 + 50*x11)*x11b + (40 + 40*x21)*x12b<=500;
```

And it prompts me as error message

> x11b not defined

I looked in several pages and its the same format. Any idea why is that¿

Comment: This is not a linear program: you are multiplying a variables. It doesn't answer why you get that error message but even if you didn't get that, it wouldn't work. GLPK can only solve linear programs.

Comment: And is there another way to redesing this multiplication?

Comment: See [Integer Programming Tricks](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_integerprogrammingtricks.pdf). I guess you are looking for 7.3 Either-or constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to define x11b would be

```
var x11b >= 0, binary
```

But as pointed in the comments, **this is not a linear program**.

Answer (score -2):

Systaxis error, it is:

```
var x11b, binary; var x12b, binary;
```